# replace all values in array that have "o" letter in php

Tags: php, str-replace, array-map, array-replace

This is my array

```
$arr = array("dog", "cat", "lion");
```

Now i wanna replace any value that has the letter o with 0.
Example :

```
$arr = array("d0g", "cat", "li0n");
```

This is my method for doing this :

```
$arr = array("dog", "cat", "lion");

$arr2 = array("d0g", "cat", "li0n");
$rep = array_replace($arr, $arr2);
var_dump($rep);
```

This method is completely manual. While I want a way to automatically track the letter 'o' in any value and move them with '0'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `array_map` (to map all values of an array to new ones using some transformation function) together with `str_replace` (to replace `o` by `0`):

```php
$arr = ['dog', 'cat', 'lion'];

$rep = array_map(fn($el) => str_replace('o', '0', $el), $arr);
```

(Note that this uses [PHP 7.4 arrow function syntax](https://stitcher.io/blog/short-closures-in-php). You can use `function ($el) { 
return str_replace('o', '0', $el) }` instead of `fn($el) => str_replace('o', '0', $el)` if you have to use an older PHP version.)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $string) {
    $arr[$key] = str_replace("o", "0", $string);
}
```

OR

```
$arr = array_map(function ($el) { return str_replace("o", "0", $el);}, $arr);
```